# Return Statement not outputting result in Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have this code written and majorly I wanted the result to print out values, combining with strings and newlines. I was also trying to avoid having the results in (). However it seems I am missing something as the result prints out nothing. 
I am aware of using the print function but the problem is this. The function is actually being rendered within a Flask html page. Using the Print results in 'None' being outputted when the html page is called. Or if there is another workaround using Print and being able to render it.
Here is a draft of the code.

```
def testline():
    str1 = 'result'
    str2 = 'devastating'
    str3 = 'Filling Wao: '

    return "The {0} for the current year is {1} \n Definition: {2} \n Wao".format(str1, str2, str3)
testline()
```

Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: `return` is not `print`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your contributions. They were close but not really the solution I needed.
I finally got a nice workaround. Like I said using the Print Statement output none on the HTML page. So i sticked to the return statement.
This time around, I only returned the variables within the function:

```
return str1, str2, str3
```

Then rendered the function via a variable **'results'** in the Routes.py page

Then I did a for loop in my HTML page using Jinja and iterating the return items alongside the strings. Something like this:

```
{% for result in results %}
<p>The {{ result[0] }} for the current year is {{ result[1] }}</p>
<p>Definition: {{ result[2] }}</p>
<p>Wao</p>
{% endfor %}
```

And gracias, when I run my browser, you can guess right that it came out just as I wanted. I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = testline()
print(result)
```

Should work !

Answer (score 0):

`return` will just return the result but not to stdout. Its good for capturing the function output via a variable.

If you want function output on stdout you can use `print()` function.

```
def testline():
    str1 = 'result'
    str2 = 'devastating'
    str3 = 'Filling Wao: '

    print("The {0} for the current year is {1} \n Definition: {2} \n Wao".format(str1, str2, str3))

testline()
```

Comment: Actually, I am aware of using the print function but the problem is this. The function is actually being rendered within a Flask html page. Using the Print results in 'None' being outputted when the html page is called.